# Javascript: Check if something can have properties _added_ to it

Tags: javascript, properties

EDIT: Made clearer that the need is to determine if I can *add* properties to a value, not if a value can *have* its own properties.

Is there a way to check if is possible to *add properties* to a `value`?

For example, if I have this code:

```
function test( value ) {
    // return true if it is possible to add properties to value
}
```

Other than actually adding a property `value` to test, is there a reliable way to deduce if `value` is something that properties can be added to?

For example, I know an `object` can have properties and `undefined` can't, but I'm not keen on creating a list of known things that might not suffice in the future. Is something like `instanceof object` sufficient?

Comment: Do you want to know if `value` can *have* properties or if you can *add* properties? Strings have properties (like length), but you can't add them.

Comment: Can add. I'll update OP to make that clearer.

Comment: By the way: What is your usecase?

Comment: Doh, forgot about the title, thanks! Updated.

Comment: @Jonas Wilms: I want to be able to add some properties & methods to a passed in value at runtime, but I don't know what the value might be in advance. If there's no reliable way to determine that I can add properties I'll have to do a load of refactoring to avoid getting in to that situation, so I guess my use case is "avoid a load of refactoring" :)

Comment: Bad usecase. You are just writing your next headache :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of values that do not have properties is quite short: `undefined` and `null`. Testing for those should be straightforward (`value == null`).

Note that all other primitives can have properties (through boxing), but as the boxed object gets lost immeadiately there is no sense in adding properties to them:

```
 1..test = 1;
 "test".test = 1;
 Infinity.test = 1;
 NaN.test = 1;
 true.test = 1;
 Symbol().test = 1;
 1n.test = 1;
```

To check for non-primitives, `typeof value === "object"` can be used, but as `null` is also an object (a very special one, actually it counts as a primitive but `typeof` lies about that), you have to explicitly check for `value !== null`.

While you can usually add properties to objects, they can be frozen, then adding properties is useless, the same applies to Proxies.

```
  const obj = {};
  Object.freeze(obj);
  obj.test = 1;
  console.log(obj.test);
```

And as Proxies can't be detected, there is no way to find out wether a property can be added or not.

Answer (score 0):

A simple idea (although it does not solve completely the case as per **Jonas Wilms** answer) may be:

```js
function test(value) {
    try {
        if (value.p === undefined) {
            value.p = 10;
            if (value.p === undefined) {
                return false;
            }
            delete value.p;
        }
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log('null: ' + test(null));
console.log('undefined: ' + test(undefined));
console.log('number: ' + test(10));
console.log('object: ' + test({a:10}));
var  obj = { get p() { return false; }, set p(v) {} };
console.log('object with property name confict: ' + test(obj));
```

Comment: What about `{ get p() { return false; }, set p(v) {} }` ? ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms You are right, indeed it is the weak side of my answer. But it is only an attempt.

Comment: Using a locally scoped Symbol instead of a string key will work around this, but I'm not sure wether this whole thread is useful at all ... I have the feeling this ends up as an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Jonas Wilms:

> Bad usecase. You are just writing your next headache :)

I need to refactor my code so it doesn't need to jump through hoops.